# How FIS creates the Alpine Skiing World cup calendar?

Tags: skiing, schedule

I guess there aren't rules for creating Alpine Skiing World Cup calendar, but I guess there is some logic behind choosing the number of the different disciplines that will be in a current cup season. For the [2016 Alpine skiing calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Alpine_Skiing_World_Cup), especially the men's one, I see 11 Downhill, 8 SuperG, 11 Giant Slaloms, 11 Slaloms and 3 Super Combined. This means that the fast skiers has advantage in 19 races (DH + SG), while the technical ones have advantage in 22 (GS + SL).
What is FIS logic behind this schedule and is it well balanced?